# Convert String to Date to time ago String

Tags: ios, swift, date

I'm receiving a String from my API which is the object creation time. The format is specific so I can't determine how it can be converted.

`2021-07-07T15:03:21.409Z`

I tried to convert it to a Date like this :

```
extension String {
 func toDate(withFormat format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") -> 
 Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr-FR")
        dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self)

        return date
    }
}
```

But it's returning `nil`. I guess the `withFormat` part isn't good in my `toDate()` function but I'm unsure about it.

Then I would like to convert it again to a time ago String like this (found on SO):

```
extension Date {
 func timeAgoDisplay() -> String {

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let minuteAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -1, to: Date())!
        let hourAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: -1, to: Date())!
        let dayAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())!
        let weekAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())!

        if minuteAgo < self {
            let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: self, to: Date()).second ?? 0
            return "\(diff) sec ago"
        } else if hourAgo < self {
            let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: self, to: Date()).minute ?? 0
            return "\(diff) min ago"
        } else if dayAgo < self {
            let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: self, to: Date()).hour ?? 0
            return "\(diff) hrs ago"
        } else if weekAgo < self {
            let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: self, to: Date()).day ?? 0
            return "\(diff) days ago"
        }
        let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: self, to: Date()).weekOfYear ?? 0
        return "\(diff) weeks ago"
    }
}
```

Comment: Call your function like this `toDate(withFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")` and it will work. Also when posting extensions to types then I think you should include what it is an extension to for clarity even if it is easy to guess.

Comment: Look at your format string. Where is the `T`, the fractional seconds and the trailing `Z`? A more convenient formatter is [ISO8601DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter). And for the *ago* stuff there is [RelativeDateTimeFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/relativedatetimeformatter)

Comment: In a text editor, put your format `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` ABOVE `2021-07-07T15:03:21.409Z`, see what's supposed to match which letter with which part: `"yyyy"` with `"2021"`, "MM" with `"07"`, do no forget also the `"-"` etc. You'll see what's wrong, like what about the `T`? The `Z`?

Comment: The format wasn't good, thanks. I'll check on RelativeDateTimeFormatter @vadian

Answer (score -2):

This is actually quite simple... The answer is simply using a formatter like so:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSSS"
let currentTime = df.string(from: Date())
//currentTime is your string. You can change date formatter as you wish!
```

In this example DateFormatter() formats dates into a certain format and then converts it!

The different parts mean: `yyyy` is a four digit year, `MM` is the month like 08 or 12 or something, `dd` is a two-digit date, `H` is the military time hours 0-24 and `hh` is the hours from 0-12 and again, `mm` are the minutes, `ss.SSSS` are the seconds and the fraction seconds up to four decimal places.

If you want the letters you can do something like this instead:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'H:mm:ss.SSSS'Z'"
let currentTime = df.string(from: Date())
```

Comment: *quite simple* but quite wrong. It doesn't match the ISO date in the question.

Comment: hey @vadian just because the question has an extra 'T' and 'Z' that doesnt make it wrong... I have it in the EXACT SAME format without the letters... its called reformatting :)

Comment: @AppDeveloper your post still wrong after your edit. Do you know what Z in a date string means? It means UTC time. If you escape the Z the date formatter will ignore it and parse the date string using the current timezone.

Comment: Second issue you are not setting the locale while parsinfg a fixed date format. You should always set its locale to "en_US_POSIX". This would prevent your dateFormat reflecting the device's locale and settings. Your parsing might fail depending on the device's 12-24h setting.

Comment: Third issue `H` is not military time. `H` means 0-23. You should use `HH` 00-23.

Comment: Fourth DateFormatter will ignore the fourth fraction digit. You can have up to 3 fraction digits when converting the date to a string. When parsing it you just need a single S to parse from 1 to 3 fraction digits. In other words `S`, `SS` or `SSS` will achieve the same results when parsing a date string with any number of fraction digits.

Comment: Fifth when converting a Date to String using your dateFormat it will result in a date string with the current timezone and it will add a Z to the resulting string which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: _"try to be a little kinder"_ note that it's the answer that got downvoted and not you personally.